# Create directory in Dockerfile using ENV variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to use docker and docker-compose to build a set of containers with some customized parameters using environment variables - for example, I want to mount a directory at a **specific** location in the container. This specific location is stored in an environment variable and created in the Dockerfile using a command like:

```
RUN mkdir $custom_location
```

I keep the parameters in an .env file which populates the docker-compose file.

Once the containers are running, using the `printenv` command I can see that the transfer of the env variables has worked and I can manually run the command 
`mkdir $custom_location` but the command hasn't been successful during the dockerfile build process.

A summarized version of the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.5 as my_base
ENV CUSTOM_PATH=$CUSTOM_PATH
RUN mkdir $CUSTOM_PATH
```

A summarized version of the docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
  service:
    environment:
      - CUSTOM_PATH=${CUSTOM_PATH}
    build: ./Docker
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

> Step 20/20 : RUN mkdir $CUSTOM_PATH  ---> Running in 437aa3f09dbb
>   mkdir: missing operand Try 'mkdir --help' for more information. The
>   command '/bin/sh -c mkdir $CUSTOM_PATH' returned a non-zero code: 1

Why would this be?

The ENV variables are successfully in the running container. Using `printenv` I can see them.

Comment: Dockerfile doesnt load .env file, so when you build the image the variable is blank... if you need to add some variable when building image you have to do `ARG` in Dockerfile and pass it there when you do `docker build -t dude --build-arg CUSTOM_PATH=cool .`

Comment: Is there no way I can avoid passing the arg as a parameter in the docker build command? I would like to avoid a síngle parameter being passed like that with the rest all loaded into docker compose from a .env file

Comment: You could add in dockerfile something like COPY .env /my_env.txt , that way you will have the content of .env in your image, and then you can do some fancy stuff with shell on that

Comment: Nice idea - thanks! Though it seems that it isn't the docker way...

Comment: i would not recommend it either and it depends on your setup, i always put .env in .gitignore and make it unique across machines. I dont know your app but you are in charge of the image (application) and i would suggest not to do this at all, just hardcode the folder and then let user in docker-compose.yml where he mounts it on his machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may successfully use `ARG` with `ENV` in your `Dockerfile`. See [the docs for this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables):

> You can use an `ARG` or an `ENV` instruction to specify variables that are available to the `RUN` instruction. Environment variables defined using the `ENV` instruction always override an `ARG` instruction of the same name. Consider this `Dockerfile` with an `ENV` and `ARG` instruction.

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG CONT_IMG_VER
ENV CONT_IMG_VER ${CONT_IMG_VER:-v1.0.0}
RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
```

So, in your case it should be

```
FROM python:3.6.5 as my_base
ARG CUSTOM_PATH=<some default path if you wish>
ENV CUSTOM_PATH=$CUSTOM_PATH
RUN mkdir $CUSTOM_PATH
```

After that you may build the image with `docker build --build-arg CUSTOM_PATH=/var/log/whatever .` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Is there any way to avoid passing the arg as a parameter of   the build command?

Comment: only to set the default value. It's all described in the docs. Read the docs.